# How does one configure VS2010 code generation features?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Sorry if this is already covered, or better asked in another of the stackoverflow properties...

What I'm looking for is a way to control how the boiler plate "create a new class" in C++ is handled in VS2010.

Currently, create a new class X with parent Y generates

```
X.h
#include "Y.h"
class X :
   public Y
{
public:
   X(void);
   virtual ~X(void);
}

X.cpp
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "X.h"

X::X(void)
{
}

X::~X(void)
{
}
```

I would prefer that every (void) be instead ().  I assume there must be a template file from which the above code is generated?  Does anyone know where that is, what the proper procedure is for overriding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer this myself, but the reality is that VS2010 (and older) don't support being able to customize the code generation for C++ (but do for other languages).

So Zannjaminderson is right if you're looking for anything but C++

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to find any for C++ on my machine, but that's likely because I only do C# development in Visual Studio, but it looks like [this blog post](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/) might have your answer.

To summarize and save future finders of this question from inevitable link rot, basically you navigate to:

```
%VS Install Path%\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\%Language%\Code\1033\Class.zip
```

Where `%VS Install Path%` is some flavor of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0` or perhaps `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0` and %Language% is `CPlusPlus` or something - not sure because my system only has `CSharp` and `VisualBasic`.

Anyways, navigate here and make a copy of the .zip file on your desktop, unzip it, and edit the contained code file to look how you like it.  Then zip it back up so it matches the original zip, copy the new .zip back to that location and navigate to this path in a command line:

```
%VS Install Path%\Common7\IDE
```

And run this command:

```
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
```

And there you have it, your template looks just how you like it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Unfortunately, for VS2010/C++, I have such a folder with some contents relating to unit testing, but none like in other language paths (e.g. C# has class.zip, which has contents as you describe).  Perhaps VS2011/2012 will move that from hard-coded out to xml files such as these?

Comment: Yeah strangely all I had was one for unit testing as well, but I still put up the answer hoping that maybe I had a strange install and others' (yours) would prove to be different.

Comment: Some more digging turns up a blog post suggesting running that final command in order to fill in templates you might be missing, so maybe that's a place to start?

Comment: Running devenv.exe /installvstemplates (required elevation) didn't create any new class.zip.  I'll just have to keep looking - or wait for the next version of Visual Studio.